# Check if Swift genericized number is above a certain percentage of its maximum value

Tags: swift, generics, swift4

I'm trying to write an extension for a genericized class. I want to be able to determine whether a variable of type `T`'s value is above a certain percentage of its maximum value.

I'm having trouble a) figuring out how to get the max value for the type, and b) getting the types converted right for the comparison.

```
public class CustomClass<T:BinaryInteger> { 
    public var someValue:T
    ...
}
extension CustomClass {
    func isOver(threshold:Float) {
        // defined for threshold between -1 and +1
        let convertedThreshold:Float = threshold * Float(T.MAX_VALUE)
        return self.someValue > T(clamping: convertedThreshold)
    }
}
```

Right now I'm stuck on getting the max value of a variable of type `T`. The [`BinaryInteger` docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/binaryinteger#2888908) mention `T.min` and `T.max` but those seem to not actually be defined.

For clarity:

If threshold is `0.5` and `T` is of type `UInt8` I want to return `true` if the variable is over 127. But if `T` is of type `UInt16` I want to return `true` if the variable is over 32,767.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [JeremyP said,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48305926/1187415) you'll need to restrict `T` to the `FixedWidthInteger`
protocol, which has a required `max` property.

For unsigned integer types, the conversation to `Float` (or `Double`) can be done via the largest unsigned integer type, `UInt64`:

```
extension CustomClass where T: UnsignedInteger {
    func isOver(threshold: Float) -> Bool {
        return Float(UInt64(self.someValue)) > threshold * Float(UInt64(T.max))
    }
}
```

(and via `Int64` for signed integer types).

Full self-contained example:

```
public class CustomClass<T:FixedWidthInteger> {
    public var someValue: T = 0
}

extension CustomClass where T: UnsignedInteger {
    func isOver(threshold: Float) -> Bool {
        return Float(UInt64(self.someValue)) > threshold * Float(UInt64(T.max))
    }
}

let x = CustomClass<UInt16>()
x.someValue = 50_000
print(x.isOver(threshold: 0.5)) // true
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting: Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UInt64' with an argument list of type '(UnsignedInteger)'

Comment: @BradDwyer: That is strange, it compiles in my Xcode 9.2 (9C40b).

Comment: I'm using the same version. I'll play around with it a bit more and see if I can figure out what I did wrong

Comment: @BradDwyer: I have added a full self-contained example. It compile in my Xcode and at https://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl.

Answer (score 3):

`BinaryInteger` does not have `min` and `max` but `FixedWidthInteger` does. All the built in integer types have this protocol.

There is a further problem that I haven't figured out yet. It's not easy to convert an arbitrary type that conforms to `FixedWidthInteger` to a `Float` or `Double`.

Comment: @LeoDabus Unfortunately using `init(exactly:)` will crash for a generic `BinaryInteger` argument, as it's [not yet implemented](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/0782b482b364f15741cc4a445976d8167c1a9d25/stdlib/public/core/FloatingPointTypes.swift.gyb#L1499) :/. The generic `init<Source : BinaryInteger>(_ value: Source)` & `init?<Source : BinaryInteger>(exactly value: Source)` initialisers have only just been implemented in https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/13782.

Comment: @Hamish I have just notice that thats why I deleted my coment

Comment: That explains whyt my attempts to use them just crashed my playground

Comment: In practice, given the magnitude of integer types, you won't be off by much if you use integer math to calculate the percentage.

Comment: @zneak - can you post how you'd do that? Integer math precision would be fine but scaling the float up to type T is still tripping me up.

Comment: @zneak I considered using integer maths but it's quite hard to write correct code that won't overflow in some circumstances.